# Creating custom cells in static row UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I tried to create app with settings. For shown settings i choose table view.

So i need to create this table. There is Apple official guide - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html But i cant understand how to set view to cells. And how should i set Sections's name?

Is there tutorial about creating such tables? I cant find anything

UPD i want to create table like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to use a UIStoryboard with a UITableViewController subclass.

Drop in a UITableView and in the Attributes Inspector select Content > Static Cells.

[image]

You can then arrange your cells and link controls with IBOutlets and actions.